# Open source IT ticket system that works well with AD for authentication

Tags: open-source, windows-server, help-desk, microsoft-exchange

I work for a company that wants to go with an open source IT ticket system that is easy to integrate for the users on our domain. We want them to be able to login with their user accounts that are on the domain.

The ticket system does not have to be super modern. We just want something that will work for us and we can track on the ticket system instead of using email which is a bad way of managing the IT problems we come across. It would be for a general office setting. This is where other departments can create tickets for IT to fix there issues. Such as my computer wont start, my keyboard is not working, the printer is out of ink, etc.

Any suggestions?

BTW the number of computers that we manage are between 90-140 systems. About 30-40 network printers.

We are wanting something that will work with exchange as well. So anytime a ticket is updated it will email a status.

#### Requirements sum-up:

- works *with* Windows
- easily integrates with our domain (MS Exchange/AD accounts)
- sends mail on status changes/updates
- deals with standard IT issues, such as "my computer wont start", "my keyboard is not working", "the printer is out of ink", etc.
- no "fancy stuff" needed – a simple ticket system suffices

Answer (score 1):

Try [OTRS](https://otrs.com/), it is free and open source.

Its authentication can be configured to use LDAP, which I believe makes it compatible with ActiveDirectory:
https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/8.0/en/content/users-groups-roles/customer-users.html#customer-user-back-end-ldap

Simple to use, possible to install on windows server. You can configure most things directly via the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

It always seems funny when people ask specifically for Open Source software that plays nicely with a specific proprietary system, in this case AD - Microsoft Active Directory.

I would suggest that validation of the users domain rights is down to AD.

- You can just use [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for your ticketing system.
- Free, Open Source & Cross Platform
- Widely used
- Web Interface
- Highly customize-able for views, tickets, workflows, users & roles
- email integration
- There is a [plug-in](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DirectoryAuthPlugin) for LDAP that plays nicely with AD, Open LDAP & Open Directory

Please, please, please consider, *whatever solution you adopt,* when setting up your ticketing system, that the user with the problem **may** have the problem of being unable to log on to the system, or run the browser, to raise their own ticket so provide for:

1. Raising tickets for other users, *e.g. the person at the next desk can't long on.*
2. Have a well known/publicized telephone number, possibly as a sticker on the edge of every monitor, for someone who can raise tickets for people who cannot *preferably one that doesn't start with a long message telling a user that cannot get on to the system that they should be using the online system*.
3. Consider if you need "out of hours" support and how people can contact it if needed.

I personally have worked in places where I have been unable to raise a ticket about password failures because I couldn't log in to raise the ticket - *in a couple of cases because IT had **emailed** me my account details and initial password **to the account that I needed them for!***  For some reason the IT staff in those companies sometimes comment that nearly every user that they come into contact with seems to be in a bad mood.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Did you have a lot of problems with being unable to login to that ticket system to raise the ticket?

Comment: @jc lots of problems due to the lack of a clear alternative, _even the phone book is online_, finally got a phone No then got routed to a call center - then the language problems started ...

Comment: Hmmmm I am not understanding. Well the way I think we would have it to contact us if they are unable to login. We would do what you said and put an extension at the edge of every monitor. I still don't understand why they would not be able to login to the Web application of the ticket system if they have AD creds.

Comment: How about if the IT problem that they have is a lost password, browser problem or a non-functioning network connection all fair;y common occurrences.

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for the clarity i understand now. Well if they are locked out we can just reset their password in AD. That is why i wanted something that works in sync with AD. If it is network issue they can call us or come visit the department. I think if it gets to that point we can then we would troubleshoot your network.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've used [OSTicket](http://osticket.com/) with LDAP authentication it works without issue. I performed several customization myself as well being familiar with PHP.

Comment: Nice! can i communicate with you if i have questions or concerns?

Comment: OSTicket DOESNT WORK WITH AD/LDAP nicely, U HAVE TO MANUAULY COPY ACCOUNTS FROM AD AND INPORT TO osTICKET,OR PAY FOR 3rd party plugin to sync it all AD with osTicket accounts